# Load div each x second and allow scroll top

Tags: jquery, html

In a chat application I would like to keep loading the div that receives the messaged posted and scroll down to the div. My issue is once the scroll down is made I cannot scroll to the top to see previous messages because the scroll down is in the setInterval function. How can I solve this or is there another way to achieve this ?

Fiddle : [jsfiddle.net/hu4zqq4x/316](http://jsfiddle.net/hu4zqq4x/316)

Thanks

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $(".messages").stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(".messages")[0].scrollHeight
  }, 1000);
  var messageTo = $("#message-to").val();
  var message_from = <?=$iduser?>;
  $('#new_message1_doc').load("<?php echo base_url("
    admin_medico / newMessageDoc ")?>?messageTo=" + messageTo + "&id_user=" + message_from);
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='messages'>
  <div id="new_message1_doc"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a generated example without PHP that shows the problem?

Comment: thank you for answer me, I posted my codes in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hu4zqq4x/316/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the position you scrolled to, and if there are no new messages this position won't be changed, in that case, don't perform the scroll.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/hu4zqq4x/318/)

```
var lastScrollPosition;
function getMessages(letter) {
    var div = $("#messages");
    if (lastScrollPosition != div.prop('scrollHeight')){
      lastScrollPosition = div.prop('scrollHeight');
      div.scrollTop(lastScrollPosition );
    }
}

$(function() {
setInterval(function(){
     getMessages();
}, 1000);

});
```

Another way is to send only new messages and then scroll only when new messages arrived.